# Does setting the bash shell option 'checkhash' actually improve the performance of bash commands?

Tags: bash, shopt

**Premise:** In the process of modifying `.bashrc`, and going through the [bash manual for shopt online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) page for the different shell options that can be handled by `shopt`, I came across the option `checkhash`, which according to the description:

```
checkhash
    If this is set, Bash checks that a command found in the hash table exists 
    before trying to execute it. 
    If a hashed command no longer exists, a normal path search is performed.
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this option useful, i.e, does it increase the performance of the bash commands?
2. If, yes, why is the **default value** set to `off`?
3. If, no, why does the option exist in the first place, is it something to do with older hardware?

Comment: Adding more tests before a command is run won't improve performance https://superuser.com/questions/733744/how-to-get-bash-to-automatically-refresh-program-locations-cache

Comment: Thanks for the link, it definitely contributes to my understanding of the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that that setting is supposed to improve the user experience, not the "performance".

It should save you from having to run `hash -r` by hand when you moved or removed an executable.

Compare:

```
bash$ mkdir -p first second; PATH=$PATH:first:second
bash$ echo echo ok > first/ok; chmod 755 first/ok
bash$ ok
ok
bash$ mv first/ok second/ok
bash$ ok
bash: first/ok: No such file or directory
   # Yet it's in the PATH!
bash$ hash -r
bash$ ok
ok
```

versus

```
bash$ shopt -s checkhash
bash$ mv second/ok first/ok
bash$ ok
ok
bash$ mv first/ok second/ok
bash$ ok
ok
bash$
```

Comment: The example clarifies the doubt. This looks like a good feature to enable; will definitely test this out.

Comment: FWIW, the `checkhash` behaviour is the default in the `zsh` shell.